# Record calls in PCM-Format

Tags: android, sip, record, pcm

I am trying to write an Android app using SIP-Based VoIP (I use SipDemo as a template).

I need to **record incoming and outgoing calls and save them in PCM-Format**.

```
private static final int RECORDER_SAMPLERATE = 44100;
private static final int RECORDER_CHANNELS = AudioFormat.CHANNEL_IN_MONO;
private static final int RECORDER_AUDIO_ENCODING = AudioFormat.ENCODING_PCM_16BIT;
```

Is it possible?

This is an activity for incoming calls:

```
public class IncomingCallReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
```

`@Override
public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
    SipAudioCall incomingCall = null;
    try {

        SipAudioCall.Listener listener = new SipAudioCall.Listener() {
            @Override
            public void onRinging(SipAudioCall call, SipProfile caller) {
                try {
                    call.answerCall(30);
                } catch (Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
        };

        WalkieTalkieActivity wtActivity = (WalkieTalkieActivity) context;

        incomingCall = wtActivity.manager.takeAudioCall(intent, listener);
        incomingCall.answerCall(30);
        incomingCall.startAudio();
        incomingCall.setSpeakerMode(true);
        if(incomingCall.isMuted()) {
            incomingCall.toggleMute();
        }

        wtActivity.call = incomingCall;

        wtActivity.updateStatus(incomingCall);

    } catch (Exception e) {
        if (incomingCall != null) {
            incomingCall.close();
        }
    }
}`

}

What is the source code I need for call recording?

Thanks in advance!